# How do I view achievements in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements

I don't know how to view my achievements. I am on Minecraft bedrock edition v.1.14.60. I have actually looked up "how to find achievements in Minecraft bedrock edition 1.14.60" on Google, but even after searching that long phrase and looking everywhere the achievements were on their screens, I still can't find achievements anywhere. Here's proof!
  [image: menu screen]
  [image: pause screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Minecraft Wiki on [Achievements](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievement):

> Achievements are tracked per user account. They are not tracked separately per world; achievements earned in one world apply to all worlds using that edition and that user account. On most platforms that Bedrock Edition runs on, achievements are logged to an Xbox Live account, and so players have to be logged in to their Xbox Live account to earn them. On PS4, Bedrock achievements are logged as trophies to the player's console account, and if logged into a PSN account and online, they are synced with PSN but not Xbox Live (even if logged into an Xbox Live account).

This means that you can find them on your Xbox account. You can root around the Xbox website under your account until you find a page that looks like this:

[image: Achievements Page]

Then just scroll down to view your achievements!

Comment: I don't have a minecraft account and my dad won't sign me in:(

Answer (score 2):

Go to Profile in the menu and you will see the achievements button. Press on it and it will show all your lifetime achievements.

In Java Edition, press L and you will see your world achievements. Or hit esc and press the achievements button.

I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Join a world or  go to the title screen, then just click profile, and then achievements. That is how it works for me. I hope it's useful. I use bedrock iPad