# How do I check my achievements on Minecraft PS4?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements

How do I check my Minecraft achievements on PS4?

Comment: This is pretty easy to search for online. Please do some research before posting a question.

Comment: Related: [How do I view achievements in minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/370780/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Trophies, select Minecraft, then check your achievements! Don't worry, I have checked achievements for other PS4 games with no problem!

Answer (score 0):

There's a given Achievements tab in the Profile tab (where you customize your skins). Upon getting in, you can see all the achievements, including ones you still didn't achieve.