# Why i cant see my achievements in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I cant find achievements, in menu, in-game, everywhere, i have searched a post on this side but it didnt worked, i checked every single setting but theres no "achievements" button.
Yes i checked the exact post saying "how i check my achievements on minecraft" (or idk name) it didnt work

Comment: Are you playing on xbox, ps, android, ios, switch, pc...?

Comment: @AJPerez is it any different on each platform

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view achievements in minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370780/how-do-i-view-achievements-in-minecraft)

Comment: I literally said that didnt work to

Comment: @AJPerez android

Comment: No, you said "*a post*" didn't work - no one can know what that post was. Please explain what didn't work, and what else you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your achievements in Minecraft you need to log in through an Xbox account (that's just a Microsoft account). Login using the Microsoft account in Minecraft. Click on *Profile* under the image of your character (Paper Doll) and click on *achievements*. You can also go to Xbox app for viewing the achievements you made and *G points* you have.

**Note: This works in PC version (Windows 10 edition formerly known as Bedrock Edition or Minecraft Now). This might or might not work with PE, I don't know.**

Edit: With the new update in Minecraft (1.17.0+) you can now see your achievements button in the menu buttons just like it used to be